# Primefaces PickList target is empty on ajax transfer listener

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have the following `p:pickList`:

```
<p:pickList id="activityUser" value="#{activityEntryController.activityUserDualListModel}" var="model" itemLabel="#{model.fullName}"
    itemValue="#{model}" converter="activityUserListConverter" styleClass="activityUser" required="true" showSourceFilter="true"
    showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Available</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Selected</f:facet>

    <p:column style="width: 400px">
        <h:outputText value="#{model.fullName}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{activityEntryController.sortUsersOnTransfer}" update="activityUser" />
</p:pickList>
```

The `value` of this `p:pickList` is a class which extends the `DualListModel<T>`:

```
public class ActivityUserDualListModel extends DualListModel<ActivityUserDTO> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5369543532197736480L;

    public ActivityUserDualListModel() {
        super();
        initModel();
    }

    public ActivityUserDualListModel(List<ActivityUserDTO> source, List<ActivityUserDTO> target) {
        super(source, target);
        initModel();
    }

    private void initModel() {
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider) ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getBean(Beans.SERVICE_PROVIDER.getName());
        IUserService userService = serviceProvider.getUserService();

        List<ActivityUserDTO> activityUserDTOs = new ArrayList<ActivityUserDTO>();

        for(User user : userService.getAllUser()) {
            if(user.isActive()) {
                activityUserDTOs.add(constructActivityUserDTO(user));
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(activityUserDTOs, ComparatorUtils.getActivityUserFullNameComparator());

        setSource(activityUserDTOs);
        setTarget(new ArrayList<ActivityUserDTO>());
    }

    private ActivityUserDTO constructActivityUserDTO(User user) {
        ActivityUserDTO activityUserDTO = new ActivityUserDTO();
        activityUserDTO.setId(user.getId());
        activityUserDTO.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        activityUserDTO.setFullName(user.getFullName());

        return activityUserDTO;
    }
}
```

I am instantiation the `ActivityUserDualListModel` from the `PostConstruct` method of the `ActivityEntryController` managed bean.

The `listener` of the `p:ajax` which fires at the time of event `transfer` is:

```
public void sortUsersOnTransfer(TransferEvent event) {      
    List<ActivityUserDTO> source = activityUserDualListModel.getSource();
    List<ActivityUserDTO> target = activityUserDualListModel.getTarget();
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    for(ActivityUserDTO dto : source) {
        System.out.println(dto.getFullName());
    }
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    System.out.println("=============================================");
    for(ActivityUserDTO dto : target) {
        System.out.println(dto.getFullName());
    }
    System.out.println("=============================================");

    if(source != null) {
        Collections.sort(source, ComparatorUtils.getActivityUserFullNameComparator());
    }

    if(target != null) {
        Collections.sort(target, ComparatorUtils.getActivityUserFullNameComparator());
    }
}
```

The strange thing is the `target` list in the above method is empty. I am unable to find what I am missing. Any pointer would be very helpful to me.

### Edit:

The following class is the converter:

```
@FacesConverter("activityUserListConverter")
public class ActivityUserListConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String submittedValue) {
        if (!(component instanceof PickList)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(submittedValue)) {
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        DualListModel<ActivityUserDTO> pickListModel = (DualListModel<ActivityUserDTO>) ((PickList) component).getValue();
        ActivityUserDTO ret = null;

        for (ActivityUserDTO activityUserDTO : pickListModel.getSource()) {
            if (activityUserDTO.getId().equals(Long.parseLong(submittedValue))) {
                ret = activityUserDTO;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ret == null) {
            for (ActivityUserDTO activityUserDTO : pickListModel.getTarget()) {
                if (activityUserDTO.getId().equals(Long.parseLong(submittedValue))) {
                    ret = activityUserDTO;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        }

        if (value instanceof ActivityUserDTO) {
            return String.valueOf(((ActivityUserDTO) value).getId());
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Also I have the following `p:commandButton` for submitting the form. Now the `actionListener` is not firing, but it fires if I remove the `p:pickList` form the xhtml.

Comment: `TransferEvent` parameter in your `sortUsersOnTransfer` has `getItems()` method which is a list of transferred objects. Can you check elements in that list, and see if it is empty?